# How can PowerShell tell me the enum type of an IIS property?

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm working with PowerShell and IIS and hitting some interesting issues with the way that PowerShell chooses to represent types.

If I run

```
Import-Module -Force WebAdministration
Get-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name "managedPipelineMode"
```

It will dutifully print out

```
Integrated
```

But if I then try to set that property as

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value "Integrated"
```

I get the exception: **`Set-ItemProperty : Integratedis not a valid value for Int32.`**. Fair enough. I know from Googling that this type is actually a `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode` enum so I would need to do something like this to make it work:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
$t = [Type]"Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name "managedPipelineMode" -Value ([int]("Integrated" -As $t))
```

That's fair enough, but my question is this: ***How can I determine the enum type for a property without using Google?***

PowerShell is convinced that the property is a string:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool" -Name "managedPipelineMode").GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Or sometimes it thinks it's a NoteProperty backed by a string:

```
(Get-Item "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool") | Get-Member -Name "startMode"

   TypeName: Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#system.applicationHost/applicationPools#add

Name      MemberType   Definition                      
----      ----------   ----------                      
startMode NoteProperty System.String startMode=OnDemand
```

But I can't figure out how to get the actual enum type out. If I could do that, I could be far more flexible in writing values to these properties. As it stands, I have to make sure that every time I set one of these properties, I have to spend time on Google (and this is assuming I can even find the correct enum type; some are trickier to track down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PowerShell is convinced that the property is a string*

This is true.  This is because the parent object of this property is not of type `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool` as you might expect, rather, it is of type `Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement`.  You can see that by executing `(Get-Item -Path "IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool").GetType().FullName`.

I believe the `ConfigurationElement` object is just a wrapper object for XML nodes in the config files used by IIS.  In which case, each property corresponds to a value in the XML config file and, therefore, would be of type `string`.  For the particular path in your example it looks like it is using the config file at 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config'.

If you are using PowerShell ISE you could take advantage of the intellisense to determine what the valid enum values are:

[image]

Otherwise, you can use the `Enum` class's static `GetNames` method:

```
[Enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode])
```

Which will give you:

> Integrated 
>   Classic

And if you know the property is an enum but you do not know exactly what type of enum you can do this:

```
[Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool].GetProperty("ManagedPipelineMode").PropertyType.FullName
```

Which will return:

> Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode

And if you don't know the enum type and don't care what the enum type is, you just want to know what the valid enum values are you can do this:

```
[Enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool].GetProperty("ManagedPipelineMode").PropertyType)
```